# Inflating view with Google Maps api v2 for Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2, android-support-library

Please help. I have tried and implemented all other solutions, but still no luck integrating google maps in my app.

The current problem is at inflating point in my fragment

```
05-21 00:17:24.629  26619-26619/com.wimedias12.orderr          E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.wimedias12.orderr.RestaurantFragments.RestaurantHomeFragment.onCreateView(RestaurantHomeFragment.java:66)
```

First thing that pops out as an answer is to reference the google services library the right way but that is set-up.

So here is my current configuration and please help me if you can.

**restaurant_home.xml** - my fragment layout where I want the map to be displayed

```
... Other fragment layout XML code ...

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:id="@+id/mapMap"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapMapppp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

... Rest of the fragment layout XML ...
```

I have tried with MapView but no luck eiter, I read that using fragment is easier.

**RestaurantHomeFragment.java** - fragment's code

```
public class RestaurantHomeFragment extends SherlockFragment {
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_home, container, false); //<-- This line breakes
 ....
}
```

This fragment is hosted in a SherlockFragmentActivity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <permission android:name="com.wimedias12.orderr.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.wimedias12.orderr.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" >
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
....
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaXxXxXXXxXxxXx-WHmjbRpFz4eOqWBXdqUtQ" />
   </application>
```

And here are my project properties, just to verify that the library well referenced.
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

@CommonsWare answer is the right one. But because I'm using Android Studio i.e. IntelliJ Idea, I feel I need to answer how I make it work.

I just removed all references from the Project Structure window and re added one by one again, and somehow it worked, the configuration is still the same as in the image shown above. I guess IntelliJ had some problems referencing the library.

So right referencing of the library is the answer.

P.S. I ended up using MapView in a SherlockFragment. Thx for the help.

Comment: Could you make a detailed answer for Android Studio/IntelliJ regarding the NoClassDefFoundError? I'm having the same problem and re-adding the references did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, and I cannot comment on that.

However, your error is normally associated with a project where you added the JAR for Google Play Services, not the entire Android library project. Here are instructions for attaching the Android library project [in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) or [from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) -- you will have to find the equivalent instructions for your IDE of choice.

Also note that you are presently attempting to use fragments in fragments, by having `RestaurantHomeFragment` inflate a layout containing `SupportMapFragment`. That is possible to do, but unless you have a strong and clear reason to do so, I wouldn't, as nested fragments add complexity.

Comment: Yeah i don't like nested fragments either but I tried using a MapView in my fragment, and have another kind of issues. Can I use a MapView in a non-map fragment? Can you show me an example of that kind of use?

Comment: @djandreski: "Can I use a MapView in a non-map fragment?" -- that is why they made it available. "Can you show me an example of that kind of use?" -- I have only written samples that use `SupportMapFragment`, sorry.

Comment: can this be issue with a wrong API key, I can try to regenerate it, or there is another exception for that kind of error.

Comment: @djandreski: "can this be issue with a wrong API key" -- no. Please re-read the second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); <--This line..I dont see why would you inflate it, like you did

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I will try to inflate the layout in an activity, but i just wanted to work it out using fragments, because of their reusability.